# How can I reset a child StackNavigator to the initial screen from a parent TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is essentially the same question at [React Native - Reset child stackNavigator to initial screen onPress of parent tabNavigator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44830823/742446) but no one is answering.

I have an app with 2 tabs defined in TabNavigator, and each tab contains a stack of screens defined with StackNavigator.

The standard behavior when switching tabs is to keep each stack's stack intact. Instead, I want to reset the stack when a user clicks on a tab.

E.g. user clicks on Tab 1, Tab 1's stack is reset to the initial screen, no matter where the user is currently.

Comment: Have you looked into `NavigationActions.reset()`?

Comment: @Tony - yes, but I don't know when to call that. My understanding is that I would call that from inside the stack for Tab 1, but only after Tab 1 was pressed. How can I tell Tab 1's stack to call `NavigationActions.reset()` ?